# How to set post_id to resolve error : 'django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_comment.post_id'?

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-models, mptt

I am using Django and attempting to add commenting functionality with AJAX. When I click on the submit button for the comment, the action is not being performed and I am instead seeing a '`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_comment.post_id`' error in the terminal. I have checked my models.py file but am unable to identify the cause of this issue. Could you please provide guidance on how to resolve this error?

model.py

```
class Comment(MPTTModel):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post ,related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

view.py

```
def single_post(request ,*args, **kwargs):
    slug=kwargs.get('slug')
    print(slug,'slug')
    pk=kwargs.get('pk')
    print(pk,'pk')
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk,slug=slug)
    allcomments = post.comments.filter(status=True)
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(
                request,
                 'posts/post_test.html',
                    { 'post': post,
                      'comment_form': comment_form,
                      'allcomments': allcomments,
                    }
                 )

def addcomment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        print(comment_form)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('body')
            user = request.user.username
            user_comment.author = request.user
            user_comment.save()
            return JsonResponse({'result2': result, 'user': user})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    
    path('test/<int:pk>/<str:slug>/',views.single_post,name ='post_detail'),
    path('commented/',views.addcomment,name='addcomment'),

]
```

if more information is require than tell me in a comments session. I will update my question with that information.
Thank you !

Comment: The `/commented/` path needs a primary key of the post you comment to.

Comment: How can I provide that ?

Comment: in the **addcomment** function you can see i am providing author name. but i dont get how i provide post id and post slug in addcomment function so that i can save that form. Please tell me if you know the way i can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have update my url
form  `path('commented/',views.addcomment,name='addcomment'),`
to `path('commented/<int:pk>/<str:slug>/',views.addcomment,name='addcomment'),`

than i also updated the add comment function
from

view.py

```
 def addcomment(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        print(comment_form)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('body')
            user = request.user.username
            user_comment.author = request.user
            user_comment.save()
            return JsonResponse({'result2': result, 'user': user})
```

to :
views.py

```
def addcomment(request,*args, **kwargs):
    slug=kwargs.get('slug')
    print(slug,'slug')
    pk=kwargs.get('pk')
    print(pk,'pk')
    print(request,'request')
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk,slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        print(comment_form,'postting')
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('body')
            user = request.user.username
            user_comment.author = request.user
            user_comment.post = post
            user_comment.save()
            return JsonResponse({'result2': result, 'user': user})
```

Than it works for me perfectly.